# Curly braces for chapter arguments

Tags: chapters

Using

```
\chapter Introduction
```

I only get the first letter `I` being printed as the chapter name.

To print the whole title, I have to use curly braces, writing

```
\chapter{Introduction}
```

or

```
\chapter {Introduction}
```

I am quite sure that Latex Commands does allow not using curly braces with function arguments.

Comment: What makes you so sure? Yes, it might be possible to change that, but that wouldn't be LaTeX any more. You can of course write a new format `:-)`

Comment: Hi, Welcome! The **macro** `\chapter` accepts one mandatory argument, either a token or a group of tokens. `Introduction` are 12 tokens. So `\chaper Introduction` is the same as `\chapter{I}` followed by `troduction`. TeX is a macro language...  Please read https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/What_is_a_%22TeX_token%22%3F (for example)

Comment: that is not specific to `\chapter`  it applies to every latex command, try `\fbox Introduction`

Comment: Does this apply to all sectioning ?

Comment: I wonder if you have been using a different format in the past (OpTeX?) which uses end-of-line rather than a brace group to define arguments for sectioning

Comment: Yes, it used tex as its back engine.

Comment: One could not write long titles that end up on the next line.  With Latex I am able to do that, and have the ending curly brace on the next line.  It is perfectly acceptable to continue the chapter title on the next in the way described, I would think.

Comment: "Does this apply to all sectioning" it applies to every command. as I say `\fbox` or  `\typeout abc`  or `\phantom xyz` or ... what would you expect to terminate the argument to chapter, a blank line?? (just a single newline is a space so could not terminate a command)

Comment: I am not discussing expectations, I just wrote a title next to the command as I used to do.

Comment: @Raksh but what did you used to use, and how did you end the argument in that case? Clearly that was not latex?

Comment: @Raksh We are trying to understand where the confusion arises, as all LaTeX guides will show curly braces here

Comment: @JosephWright I have just seen (following your hint) that optex does terminate `\chap` at end of line (not just a blank line) it goes to a lot of effort to achieve that I think:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear how you would expect the argument of `\chapter` to be delimited if not by a `}`. It would be possible to make the argument end at a blank line (`\par`) but no standard latex command does that.

`\chapter Introduction` is `\chapter{I}ntroduction` just as

`\fbox abc`  is  `\fbox{a}bc` or

`x^10`  is `x^{1}0`

While there are some technical differences in these examples the end result is the same. In all cases the argument is a `{}` brace group, or a single token if the braces are omitted.

Comment: I will use the curly braces.

Comment: I can understand from your example `x^{1}0`.